# Email & Password validation (SwiftUI)

Tags: validation, swiftui, email-validation

I have a problem generating an error text.

```
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = "Vignesh123!"
    
    private func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
    }
    
    private func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool{
        let passwordFormat = "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}"
        let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordFormat)
        return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
    }
    
    private func validView() -> String? {
        if !self.isValidEmail(email) {
            return "Email is invalid"
        }
        
        if !self.isPasswordValid(password) {
            return "Password is invalid"
        }
        
        // Do same like other validation as per needed
        
        return nil
    }
```

during the code I wrote, I used TextField for the password to appear.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                if password.isEmpty {
                    Text("Email is Not Valid")
                        .font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.red).hidden()
                }   else if (self.validView() != nil) {
                    Text("Email is Not Valid")
                        .font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(3)
                }
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TextField("Password", text: $password)
                    .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                if password.isEmpty {
                    Text("Password is Not Valid")
                        .font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.red).hidden()
                }   else if (self.validView() != nil) {
                    Text("Password is Not Valid")
                        .font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(3)
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                
                // Show error message here
                if let errorMessage = self.validView() {
                    print(errorMessage)
                    return
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Login")
                    .frame(height: 45).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            })
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
```

**result should be** an error text should appear when I enter an inappropriate email / password and click on the Login

the above codes are my attempts

I may be making elementary mistakes, I hope you understand correctly.
I appreciate your attention, thank you all

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

why dont you use a @State var showErrorMessage:Bool
In your password and email valid functions toggle the showErrorMessage. So if password is wrong toggle to true and if password is not wrong toggle to false.

On button click call this showErrorMessage, if true then show the Text.